# How I do set a row in the HTML table in webrowser in c# 2010

Tags: c#

How doing I  select a row of the table is displayed in the tool webrowser by value in the first cell and the cell five Id
I'm try by this code ...

```
HtmlElementCollection tTABLES = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table");
int r = 0;
int c = 0;
foreach (HtmlElement TBL in tTABLES)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement ROW in TBL.All)
    {
        r += 1;
        foreach (HtmlElement CELL in ROW.All)
        {
            c += 1;
            if (p == CELL.Children[c].InnerText)//p=student id
           {
                HtmlElement reportDropDown = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_DynamicGrid_ctl0" + r + "_ctl0" + (c + 3));
                reportDropDown.Focus();
                reportDropDown.SetAttribute("value", "2");  //The value of the desired selection
                reportDropDown.InvokeMember("onchange");
                reportDropDown.RemoveFocus();
                label6.Text = CELL.InnerText.Contains("1096724024").ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not do this like you're doing, send back the modified data and render it on the page... I'm assuming WebForms right?

Comment: I'm sorry for everything 
But this translation google
And I want to solve my problem only

Comment: I think if you tell me the page you have navigated, I can help you better.

Comment: I don't know what you mean of page navigated

Comment: I changed some of the words in question are perhaps clarify question

Answer (score 0):

Where experiences?
I just want to know how I select a row from table in webrowser by the value contained in one of its cells and by the Id of another cell is using (if .... then)statement

like this one

`if (( CELL.Children[c].InnerText == "123456789") &(CELL.Children[(c+3)].Id == "ctl0_"
 + r + "_ctl0" + (c + 3)))

{

//..........................

//..........................

}`

Is building this way the condition is true
I want to select a row in a table HTML on the site displayed in the tool Webrowser
The test program so that all table rows and row conditions which apply to it changes the content of its cells